# pdfJet for .net - pdf.Flush(); - this gives me an error whn trying the example

Tags: c#, pdf

1)    A call to PInvoke function 'PDFjet!PDFjet.NET.OptionalDeflateStream::compress' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

What is this? If I remove zlibwapi.dll from the same folder as the PdfJet assembly I get: 
2)Unable to load DLL 'zlibwapi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) (note that I don't add reference to this assembly, I only copy it to Debug folder, and get error1)

code:

```
   `static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fos = new FileStream("Example_05.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        BufferedStream bos = new BufferedStream(fos);

        PDF pdf = new PDF(bos);
        pdf.setCompressor(Compressor.ORIGINAL_ZLIB);

        // Before you enable this flag please read README.ZLIB.TXT
        // in the 'optional' directory.

        // If PDF/A is not required use Helvetica, TimesRoman or Courier
        Font f1 = new Font(pdf, "Helvetica");
        /*
                Font f1 = new Font(pdf,
                        new FileStream(
                                "fonts/DroidFonts/DroidSans.otf", FileMode.Open),
                        CodePage.UNICODE,
                        Embed.YES);
        */
        Page page = new Page(pdf, Letter.PORTRAIT);

        TextLine text = new TextLine(f1);
        text.SetPosition(300.0, 300.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 15)
        {
            text.SetTextDirection(i);
            text.SetUnderline(true);
            // text.SetStrikeLine(true);
            text.SetText("             Hello, World -- " + i + " degrees.");
            text.DrawOn(page);
        }

        text = new TextLine(f1, "WAVE AWAY");
        text.SetPosition(70.0, 50.0);
        text.DrawOn(page);

        f1.SetKernPairs(true);
        text.SetPosition(70.0, 70.0);
        text.DrawOn(page);

        f1.SetKernPairs(false);
        text.SetPosition(70.0, 90.0);
        text.DrawOn(page);

        f1.SetSize(8);
        text = new TextLine(f1, "-- font.SetKernPairs(false);");
        text.SetPosition(150.0, 50.0);
        text.DrawOn(page);
        text.SetPosition(150.0, 90.0);
        text.DrawOn(page);
        text = new TextLine(f1, "-- font.SetKernPairs(true);");
        text.SetPosition(150.0, 70.0);
        text.DrawOn(page);

        Point point = new Point(300.0, 300.0);
        point.SetShape(Point.CIRCLE);
        point.SetFillShape(true);
        point.SetColor(RGB.BLUE);
        point.SetRadius(37.0);
        point.DrawOn(page);
        point.SetRadius(25.0);
        point.SetColor(RGB.WHITE);
        point.DrawOn(page);

        pdf.Flush();
        bos.Close();
    }`
```

note: the code is the exact example provided on pdfJet website: [pdfjet](http://pdfjet.com/index.html)

Comment: You haven't even included a P/Invoke definition in the code you've shown. There's no way for anyone to tell you what's wrong with it. The error messages are pretty clear; I'm not really sure what you can't figure out.

Comment: It is something with pdfjet. The exeption is thrown by Flush(). That is all I know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed   pdf.setCompressor(Compressor.ORIGINAL_ZLIB); and it works

Answer (score 0):

From your (sample) code:

```
// Before you enable this flag please read README.ZLIB.TXT
// in the 'optional' directory.
```

From the README.ZLIB.TXT...:

> The .NET version of PDFjet is using
>   the DeflateStream privided by the
>   framework. DeflateStream however does
>   not compress data as well as the
>   original zlib library.
>
> If you are running PDFjet **on 32 bit
>   version of Windows** and want it to
>   create smaller PDF files - copy
>   zlibwapi.dll to the same directory
>   where PDFjet.dll is installed.
>
> When zlibwapi.dll is not used PDFjet
>   is 100% pure managed code. When
>   zlibwapi.dll is used - you get better
>   compression and smaller PDF files.

Emphasis mine. So you are on 32bit then, I guess? And you absolutely need the unmanaged compression and cannot just return to the managed one?

Comment: If I remove zlibwapi.dll from the folder I get Unable to load DLL 'zlibwapi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E). I can live without compression. If you have a working example, could you please send me an archive with the complete solution? It would help me alot to have a working example. If yes, I will send you my email